# What is the meaning of Karni Mata's description as a woman with a head in her hand?

Tags: temple, goddess, symbolism

What's the meaning of [Karni Mata's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karni_Mata) depiction as a woman with a head in hand, a lion behind her and rats on the floor? What is her story?

> Also known as Shri Karniji Maharaj, she is worshiped as the
>   incarnation of the warrior goddess Durga by her followers. She is
>   an official deity of the royal families of Jodhpur and Bikaner.

Comment: Who is Karni Mata?

Comment: @Rickross a goddess from rajasthan- the founder king of bikaner got divine vision of devi as an old lady before he founded bikaner. She is worshipped as devi Karni in rajasthan.

Comment: Ok and we already have a goddess who is depicted as an old lady - Dhumavati. So, there can be some link between them? @Anisha

Comment: @Rickross no she is literally considered a manifestation of Durga, but like how goddess sometime takes form of young girl-old lady for her leela, in temple sculptures devi Karni is killing a buffalo with a trident. So she is Durga.

Answer (score 1):

It was Rao kandha, King of jangloo the Empire, he was cruel king.

Maa Karni was an avatar of Maa hinglaj. When she came to jangloo she at that king is so cruel and misbehaving, he also disrespect Maa, and came to Maa place where she use to stay, with his army, and Maa draw a line and said if you cross this line, you will die. And the arrogant king ignoring Mata words cross the line, and Maa lion cut, s his body into parts. And make the kingdom of jangloo a peaceful place.

You aren't familiar today jodhpur was also established by Maa Karni and bikaner too.

Actually story start with Maa awad and her seven sister, are avatar of Maa Parvati.
So mamadiya ji was the, bhakti of Maa hinglaj, it was very difficult to reach hinglaj Mata temple, it was around 2000 years ago, he was such a big bhakt that he had completed 7 trip to Maa hinglaj.
As last Maa hinglaj gave Darshan to him and ask his wish, he said Maa I have no child, so can you give boon of a child and then hinglaj Maa said.
Maa it is very difficult, since you wife does.n, t gave uterus, but I will take birth at your house as a seven sister.
And mamadiya ji request to his house, one day when mamadiya ji was taking out the milk of cow, seven white mice suddenly jump form the utensils and straight away goes to the ,baby chair   and seven sister were sleeping on the bed.